# Unable to download a pdf file from database, it show plain notepad out

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to do an ahref that able to download pdf file from database but after i click it download a plain notepad instead of pdf and no data inside.

This is the a href

```
<a href="download.php?id=<?php=$id;?>">Download [pfd]</a> <br>
```

This is download.php

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password=""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="is"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="publication"; // Table name 

        $conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password"); 
        if(! $conn )
        {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db_name);

    if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])) { 

            $id= $_GET['id'];

            $query = "SELECT file_name, file_type, file_size, content " .
                     "FROM $tbl_name WHERE file_id = '$id'";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
            list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            header("Content-length: $size");
            header("Content-type: $type");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
            echo $content;

            mysql_close($conn);
            exit;
            }


?>
```

I have store filename, type, size and content inside database but unable to download them as pdf. file type is application/pdf.

Comment: What is the type of "content" field in Mysql?

Comment: @mesutozer.. it's longblob...

Comment: Does the downloaded file have correct filename?

Comment: hmmm ... what do u means correct filename ?

Comment: I mean is the downloaded file named same as "file_name" field in DB. Or it has a generic name like "download(1)"?

Comment: ya ... it generate "download(1)" when i click on the ahref...

Comment: Then I have a guess :) please see below my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your **resultset is empty**: your query did not match any rows. This explains empty file content & empty file name.

As this page forces file download even if there is an error, you might be missing the error message. You can try to temporarily remove download headers to see the error. Also tro to open download link in a new window by pressing CTRL while you click the link. This way you can verify download URL really contains an ID.

BTW: You have **SQL injection** vulnerability in your code

Comment: the download link is http://localhost/isiti/download.php?id=%3C?php=$id;?%3E... is it means i did pass the ID to download.php ?

Comment: You are passing it incorrectly. It seems you are opening a <?php while you are already in php context. You need to remove <?php and ;?> tags surrounding the id

Comment: It seems you are printing the link like echo '<a href="download.php?id=<?php=$id;?>">Download [pfd]</a>'; you need to replace it with echo '<a href="download.php?id='.$id.'">Download [pfd]</a>'

Comment: yes ... it's works ... thank a lot ... without ur help i might nvr fix it ... thx ..

Comment: Can you check my second comment? It seems you are in an echo statement within single quotes

Comment: yes ... it's works ... thank a lot ... without ur help i might nvr fix it ... thx ..